# covering test class if condition for a variable defined in method

Tags: apex, code-coverage, class

```
public static String myMethod(String vehicle1){
    string abc = 'car';
    if (abc == 'bike'){
        // lines of code
    }
}
```

Here the issue that I am facing is that the lines of code inside the IF block are not getting captured while calling the method (myMethod) from test class. I am not able to get how to set variable value in test class.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this is mostly an issue of how you've chosen to share your code (i.e. what you've shared with us is not your *actual* code, and you've made some mistakes in trying to obfuscate your code), but...

As written, that if block is impossible to enter and impossible to test. The local variable `abc` is not accessible from outside of `myMethod()`, so it cannot be set by a test. Being able to write some code is really only the first step here. The next step for you to take is to think about *how you're going to test the code you write* (as you design and write it).

Generally speaking, in a test you are able to

- Pass arguments into methods that you call directly
- Insert test records for SObjects that the code being tested queries
- Set the values of `public` static and member variables of your class(es) (or those with the `@testVisible` annotation, but it's generally best to use that sparingly)

So you'll need to adjust your code (the code you're trying to test) so you can use one of those mechanisms in your test to control the execution path.

The simplest 'fix' here would be to replace all instances of the local variable `abc` with your method parameter `vehicle1`. That would allow you to control whether or not you enter that `if` block in your test simply by changing how you call your method.

`MyClass.myMethod('car');` would then cause you to not enter that `if` block.
`MyClass.myMethod('bike');` would cause you to enter that `if` block.

Comment: and as an aside, you should generally have a separate test method for each branch your code can take (as opposed to just mashing everything into a single test method).